# Инкапсуляция в классе

Tags: ооп, классы, php

Написал один из своих первых классов, мне сказали что там нет ООП и инкапсуляции, но поскольку я еще не опытный в этом, подскажите, почему и где проявляется отсутствие ООП и инкапсуляции https://github.com/foozzi/typical_proger/blob/master/class/lib.User.php

Comment: Я не спец по PHP, но то, что все функции объявлены, как static, настораживает. Объясните, какую _сущность_ моделирует ваш класс: поезд? мотор автомобиля? студента? матрицу? Если не можете ответить на вопрос, возможно, у вас неправильный дизайн: класс **должен** моделировать какой-нибудь штуку из реальности, а не просто быть несвязанной группой функций в одном файле.

Comment: @foozzi

- По делу — первый комментарий. Если вы честно попробуете ответить на вопрос про *сущность*, то у вас получится ответ "ну, эта такая `helper`-штука, которая занимается аутентификацией пользователей, называется `Auth` и расположена в файле `lib.User.php`". Для нормально задизайненных сущностей ответ должен быть четким, простым, понятным и даваться в течение 10 секунд.

- `OOP` ради `OOP` — это неправильно. `OOP` является подходом к решению задачи и нельзя каким-то образом (пусть даже **правильным**) решить задачу, а потом добавить в это решение немного `OOP` и инкапсуляции.

Answer (score 1):

Если пока немного опыта, то лучше использовать проверенный framework с хорошим качеством кода и придерживаться его стиля, смотреть как делабт остальные в используемых популярных библиотеках.

И обязательно прочитать PSR и придеживаться их.

Также желательно сразу приучаться писать модульные тесты - это заставит задуматься о том что и как писать, самому понять очевидные недочёты архитектуры.

Answer (score 0):

Утверждение, что у вас нет ООП, не совсем корректное. ООП - это совокупность подходов, использование объектов и классов, инкапсуляция, наследование и полиморфизм. Вы используете ООП (не обязательно использовать все элементы ООП одновременно), другое дело, что возможно используете не совсем типично.

У вас все методы класса объявлены статическими. Т.е. вы используете класс как контейнер методов, которые вызываются без создания объекта. Таким образом, вы сохраняете состояние на уровне статических переменных класса. Это нормально и такой подход используется, когда вам нужно сохранить состояние для всей совокупности объектов данного класса (например, счетчик созданных объектов или адрес формы аутентификации). Однако, насколько можно судить ваша задача заключается в аутентификации пользователей. Пользователей много и состояния у них разные: кто-то уже прошел аутентификацию, кто-то еще только собирается, кто-то в процессе. Т.е. вы не можете одной статической переменной, которая общая для всех объектов класса описать состояния всех пользователей. Лучше отказаться от статических переменных класса и статических методов в пользу объектов, по одному объекту на каждого из ваших пользователей. Таким образом вы можете работать с состоянием конкретного пользователя и хранить его состояние в закрытых переменных объекта, а не класса.